# Sql to get all cities in a country given a tree type databsae

Tags: sql

I have been given a table like this

```
Id  Name     Type      ParentId

1    US       country    -1
2    NY        state      1
3    NYC       city       2
4   Yonkers    city       2
5   Washington state      1
6   Seattle    city       5
7   Tacoma     city       5  
8   Canada     country    -1
9   Manitoba    state      8
```

I want to write a sql query to write the all cities in a state.

Example

```
Country state city
US      NY     NYC
US      NY      Yonkers
```

I get that I need to write a recursive query but not able yo do so. I need help to write a sql for this.

Comment: Using `-1` to signal "no parent" is  a really bad design, because it means you are not defining any foreign keys in your table. You should be using `NULL` instead

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't get this completely, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: You have rows with `parentid = -1` presumably to state the fact that this row does not have a parent. However there is no row with `id = -1` which means that `parentid` can't (and isn't) declared as a foreign key that ensures that you can only store values in `parentid` that reference an existing `id` value. The rows that do not have a parent should have `null` in the column `parentid`. Then you can declare a proper foreign key constraint from `parentid` to `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.name country, t2.name state, t3.name city
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
JOIN table t3 ON t2.id = t3.parent_id
WHERE t2.name = 'NY';
```

Comment: Can you please explain your query. why we need 2 joins here ?

Comment: @david We join 3 copies of the table. `t1` will select the country, `t2` - the state, and `t3` - the city. Without WHERE this will produce all possible combinations (comment this clause and loot the output). The state is given - so we apply the condition by according table and receive only those combinations which matches this condition.

Comment: @david It is possible that you need in non-complete combinations too (for example, Canada-Manitoba have no any city, and in my query it won't be returned) then use LEFT JOIN instead of single JOIN (which is INNER JOIN). But the output will contains NULLs in such case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive cte as (
   select id, name, type, parentid
   from the_table
   where type = 'state'
     and name = 'NY'
     
   union all
   select c.id, c.name, c.type, c.parentid
   from the_table c
     join cte p on p.id = c.parentid
)
select *
from cte
where type <> 'state';
```

The above is standard ANSI SQL, but not all database products support this exact syntax.

If the number of levels is fixed (so it's always Country -> State -> City) and will never change, you can use a simpler query:

```
select c.*
from the_table c
where parentid in (select s.id
                   from the_table s
                   where s.type = 'state' 
                     and s.name = 'NY');
```